# Power Automation for Paginated Report with Parameter

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I have a paginated report with Parameter and I have to create a flow for a subscription.
If I do not have the parameter the power automate flow is working but when it comes to the parameter I am not able to set it right in the flow. For example, if the user uses the parameter "City Name" in the paginated report the power automate flow does not recognize it and returns some error. How to set up the parameter in the flow. DO I have to add an action Initialized Variable to I can directly hardcode the parameter name "City Name" in the parameter Name box and parameter value Box?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can hard-code the parameter name.  But make sure you use the Parameter Name, not the Parameter Prompt.  eg:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response but I need to make it a dynamic selection because parameter values list is long

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I do not want to hardcode any parameters